# Javascript objects array

Tags: javascript, arrays, openlayers

I was following this tutorial and figured out how to center the map where I want and how to place a marker where I want.

https://medium.com/attentive-ai/working-with-openlayers-4-part-2-using-markers-or-points-on-the-map-f8e9b5cae098

However I need to add more than one marker. In the article it says "*If you want to add multiple markers, you can add multiple feature objects array to the feature key of the source object, this way you can show more than one marker on the map.*", but I don't know how to do that. Can anyone help?

**Edit 1:**

I am retrieving the coordinates from a database using ASP.Net C# code behind and generating the javascript like so:

```
strMapScript += "<script type=\"text/javascript\">" + Environment.NewLine;
strMapScript += "var baseMapLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({" + Environment.NewLine;
strMapScript += "source: new ol.source.OSM()" + Environment.NewLine;
strMapScript += "});" + Environment.NewLine;
strMapScript += "var map = new ol.Map({" + Environment.NewLine;
strMapScript += "target: 'map'," + Environment.NewLine;
strMapScript += "layers: [ baseMapLayer]," + Environment.NewLine;
strMapScript += "view: new ol.View({" + Environment.NewLine;
strMapScript += "center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([??.264861,??.0527032]), " + Environment.NewLine;
strMapScript += "zoom: 16" + Environment.NewLine;
strMapScript += "})" + Environment.NewLine;
strMapScript += "});" + Environment.NewLine;
//Adding a marker on the mapvar
foreach (DataRow drCoordinate in dtblCoordinates.Rows)
{
  strMapScript += "marker = new ol.Feature({geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(" + Convert.ToString(drCoordinate["Coords"]) + ")),});" + Environment.NewLine;
  strMapScript += "var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({features: [marker]});" + Environment.NewLine;
  strMapScript += "var markerVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({source: vectorSource,});" + Environment.NewLine;
  strMapScript += "map.addLayer(markerVectorLayer);" + Environment.NewLine;
}
strMapScript += "</script>";
```

**Edit 2:**

Based on your comments and answers, I adapted the last part of the code to look like this, and it works:

```
//Adding a marker on the mapvar
foreach (DataRow drCoordinate in dtblCoordinates.Rows)
{
  strMapScript += "marker" + Convert.ToString(drCoordinate["Id"]) + " = new ol.Feature({geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(" + Convert.ToString(drCoordinate["Coords"]) + ")),});" + Environment.NewLine;
  lstMarkers.Add("marker" + Convert.ToString(drCoordinate["Id"]) + "");
}
strMapScript += "var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({features: [" + String.Join(",",lstMarkers) + "]});" + Environment.NewLine;
strMapScript += "var markerVectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({source: vectorSource,});" + Environment.NewLine;
strMapScript += "map.addLayer(markerVectorLayer);" + Environment.NewLine;
```

Comment: It would help to add the relevant piece of code to your question.

Comment: Add another marker, `features: [marker1, marker2, ...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like

```
var marker1 = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
    ol.proj.fromLonLat([-74.006,40.7127])
  ),  // Cordinates of New York's site
});
var marker2 = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
    ol.proj.fromLonLat([-14.006,40.7127])
  ),  // Cordinates of New York's center
});
var marker3 = new ol.Feature({
  geometry: new ol.geom.Point(
    ol.proj.fromLonLat([-64.006,40.7127])
  ),  // Cordinates of New York's Town Hall
});

var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [marker1,marker2,marker3]
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have `marker1` and `marker2` markers:

```js
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
  features: [marker1, marker2]
});
```